# R package: install dependencies recursively

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I'm trying to install one of my R packages from Github using devtools (more precisely, `install_github`). But, even if a I set the parameter `dependencies` to `TRUE`, dependencies are not being installed recursively. That is, the dependencies of the dependencies are not being installed. Therefore, the package is not installed. R sends a message saying it could not find one of those dependencies. It keeps sending those messages until I install everything.

Is it a standard behaviour? Or am I missing something? The package I'm talking about is this one: https://github.com/pedrocostaferreira/BETS.

I've never had this problem when installing other people's packages. Since my package has several imports and suggestions, it would be REALLY annoying for my users to install every dependency dependencies one by one, by hand. What should I do?

Snippet of the DESCRIPTION file:

```
Depends:
R (>= 3.2.0)
Imports: 
    testthat (>= 0.9.1),
    rootSolve, 
    ggplot2, 
    plotly, 
    urca, 
    TTR, 
    forecast, 
    TSA, 
    FinTS, 
    fpp, 
    stringi, 
    sqldf, 
    foreign, 
    lmtest, 
    normtest, 
    zoo, 
    rugarch,
    colorspace, 
    fracdiff, 
    tseries, 
    timeDate,
    htmlwidgets, 
    quadprog, 
    Rcpp, 
    gtable, 
    scales, 
    viridis
Suggests:
    grnn,
    Rsolnp,
    numDeriv,
    spd,
    ks,
    SkewHyperbolic,
    expm,
    DBI,
    RSQLite,
    gsubfn,
    tidyr,
    dygraphs,
    munsell,
    plyr,
    rmarkdown,
    nloptr,
    chron,
    gridExtra,
    xts
```

Large indeed, right?

Some people suggested that if the package was already on CRAN, it wouldn't be happening. Does it make sense?

Comment: What package is this?

Comment: Dependencies are automatically resolved when you use the _proper package installation functions_ such as `install.packages()` and a repository --- and you can always build a local repository, even on GitHub for free, via [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html).

Comment: @RichScriven it's this one: https://github.com/pedrocostaferreira/BETS. I'll include this info in the question.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I'm using devtools::install_github to install it. Still, isn't working

Comment: did the small script in the [readme](https://github.com/pedrocostaferreira/BETS/blob/master/README.md) work?

Comment: You can try `pacman` [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pacman/vignettes/Introduction_to_pacman.html). It can install from github.

Comment: What's the error message? Did you mean some package are not even being attempted to install? Is it possible that some packages failed to install because of some related packages are loaded? Try with new R session?

Comment: @rawr yeah, we tried to make this script based on a fresh installation of R and it works, BUT it is SO incoveninent to install all thoses packages by hand. I want to get rid of that README

Comment: Many packages are listed as `suggests` in `DESCRIPTION`, which means they should be optional. However some of them are imported in `NAMESPACE`, so you do have to install them. But they didn't get installed automatically because they are listed under `Suggest`.

Comment: If you are the package author(even if you are not, you can always fork it), you can try to move all the packages to `Imports` in `DESCRIPTION`, if they are really required. You can read the [`Namespace` chapter of Hadley's book `R package`](r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.htm) for more details. This way it should be installed by devtools automatically.

Comment: If the packages in `Suggest` is really optional and you don't want user to install them all, then don't import them in `NAMESPACE`, use full qualified function name `package::function` instead. `Every package mentioned in NAMESPACE must also be present in the Imports or Depends fields.`

Comment: @TalithaSperanza You are doing it wrong: `install_github()` is a band-aid that does not know about _package_ (as opposed to source) repositories.  Just manually install all the required packages either in one call to `install.packages()` or (maybe better) loop and check that each one installs.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is there are inconsistency in `DESCRIPTION` and `NAMESPACE`. Many packages are imported in `NAMESPACE`, which required them to be in `Imports` or `Depends` fields of `DESCRIPTION`. However they are listed under `Suggests` which means they are optional, so they are not installed automatically. But your package do need them installed before working.

Method 1: move all packages to `Imports` in `DESCRIPTION`, then `devtools` should install them all.

Method 2: If you don't really need all of them for certain usage, and you don't want to install them all, do not import them in `NAMESPACE`. Use full qualified name `package::functionname` instead.

Read [Namespace chapter of Hadley's book R package](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html) for more details